# Hashicorp auto unseal with Azure vault

Tags: bash, azure, identity, hashicorp-vault

Hashicorp Vault added auto unseal feature, but there is no clear instructions how to set it up
Here is a link, [Unseal with Azure](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/seal/azurekeyvault.html)

```
seal "azurekeyvault" {
  tenant_id      = "46646709-b63e-4747-be42-516edeaf1e14"
  client_id      = "03dc33fc-16d9-4b77-8152-3ec568f8af6e"
  client_secret  = "DUJDS3..."
  vault_name     = "hc-vault"
  key_name       = "vault_key"
}
```

Problem: to set them up with some bash scripting

Things made based on [Azure MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-authentication-managed-identity)

Create Azure Vault

```sh
vault_name="some_name" &&\
rg="my_resource_group" &&\
location="eastus" &&\
az keyvault create --name ${vault_name} --resource-group ${rg} --location ${location}
```

Create Vault Key

```sh
vault_key="vault-key" &&\
az keyvault key create --name ${vault_key} --vault-name ${vault_name}
```

Create Managed Service Identity

```sh
msi_name="vault" &&\
az identity create --name ${msi_name} --resource-group ${rg} --location ${location}
```

Add MSI access to the Vault

```
principalID=$(az identity show --resource-group ${rg} --name ${msi_name} --query principalId --output tsv) &&\
az keyvault set-policy --name ${vault_name} --resource-group ${rg} --object-id ${principalID} --secret-permissions get set list
```

Get the values

```
tenant_id=$(az identity show --name ${msi_name} --resource-group ${rg} --query "tenantId" --output tsv)
client_id=$(az identity show --name ${msi_name} --resource-group ${rg} --query "clientId" --output tsv)
```

How can I get a "client_secret" ?

```sh
client_secret_url=$(az identity show --name ${msi_name} --resource-group ${rg} --query "clientSecretUrl" --output tsv)
curl --http1.1 ${client_secret_url}
```

Curl returns me error, no matter if I add "api-version" line, Googled:

"Required parameter api-version is missing or invalid."

What is the right way to get these values? How can I get "client_secret" right?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using MSI, you can omit client_id and client_secret.

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/seal/azurekeyvault.html

The doc link above could have been more straightforward but it does say `client_id (string: <required or MSI>):`

here's my ansible template:

```
seal "azurekeyvault" {
  tenant_id      = "{{ tenant_id[item] }}"
  vault_name     = "{{ azure_keyvault_name }}"
  key_name       = "{{ azure_keyvault_key }}"
}
```